# Prevent Home Button Press Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am creating an App for my little one because she loves the phone but messes up my Desktop. I am doing my application using NDK and I have the following....

```
static int32_t handle_input(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event) {
  if (AInputEvent_getType(event) == AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_KEY)
  {
    int key_val = AKeyEvent_getKeyCode(event);
    switch(key_val){
      case AKEYCODE_BACK:
        LOGI("Back Button hit");
        break;
      case AKEYCODE_HOME:
        LOGI("HOME HIT");
        break;
    }
    LOGI("Input Recieved %d", key_val);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

But when I hit the back button and then the home button I see...

```
I/native-activity(24450): Back Button hit
I/native-activity(24450): Input Recieved 4
I/native-activity(24450): Back Button hit
I/native-activity(24450): Input Recieved 4
I/ActivityManager(  278): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 278
```

Is there a permission or something I can give it to allow me to catch the home button press? It seems like there should be per this test class...

```
TEST_F(KeyboardInputMapperTest, Process_SimpleKeyPress) {
  const int32_t USAGE_A = 0x070004;
  const int32_t USAGE_UNKNOWN = 0x07ffff;
  mFakeEventHub->addKey(DEVICE_ID, KEY_HOME, 0, AKEYCODE_HOME, POLICY_FLAG_WAKE);
```

Comment: Are you rooted? With root access I could write something up for you.

Comment: I am trying to do it without root, however, my emulator is rooted so I could POC it there. Would it involve editing InputDispatcher.cpp?

Comment: You're right. However without root there is now way this can be done.. You're going to have to think of something clever I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are developing with the Java SDK or the NDK.  Key events for the HOME button are not sent to your application.  This is by design, the HOME button is a universal function on an Android device and applications should not be able to modify its behavior.

Comment: I hear you from a Spec perspective, however, from a theoretical (which is what I am referring to) I am not sure this is the case. I do think the last comment was right I would probably have to rewrite InputDispatcher.cpp or some such.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Getting this data into an application will require customizing Android and the framework itself.

Comment: sir, i wanted to know if it is possible to switch my android device screen on when pressing the home button, just the way samsung does. Hoe could thy be doing so? Please guide.